# Something internal not getting access after adding wampcra authentication

Tags: php, thruway

I just added wampcra authentication to my ThruwayBundle configuration and when the server is started with `thruway:router:start` my autobahn client can connect successfully. But when starting with `thruway:process start` the log is continuously appended with output indicative of some internal client (using PawlTransportProvider) not being able to connect because it too is obliged to use wampcra and the hello message it sends specifies "anonymous" as auth_id and empty authentication method list.

- How can I find out what is trying to connect that way?
- How do I make it work, do I add a username/key to that client or do I have to make the realm accept anonymous authentication instead, or something else still?

Thanks for any insight into this matter. (I sure wish there'd be more extensive documentation available...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple case of misconfiguration.

If you're experiencing the same problem, ascertain that there is a voryx_thruway.trusted_url key and that it differs from the normal url.

That solved it. Apparantly some internal client was trying to connect, assuming the address it was using arrived at the trusted port, which in my case was the same as the one expecting clients to authenticate using wampcra.